# get position of checked checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a weird problem pertaining to getting the position of the selected files. 
It can only get up to first 6 file. If I select on the 7th file, then it will return nothing. If i just click on the 7th file. It will return me as the first file.

Edit: I think the problem is due to the view get changed when I scroll, and the checkbox get reset.

Here's part of my code.

```
private boolean[] selection;  
private int count;
private List<Media> getMediaList = new ArrayList<Media>();
private ArrayList<String> storeSelectedMedia = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE
    };

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        getMediaList.add(new Media (cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(5)));
        //Log.i("media", "" + cursor.getString(5));
    }

    cursor.close ();
    count = getMediaList.size();  
    Log.i("MediaSize", "" + count);
    selection = new boolean[count];  

    ArrayAdapter<Media> adapter = new MyMediaAdapter(this, getMediaList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

public class MyMediaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Media> {

    private final List<Media> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public MyMediaAdapter(Activity context, List<Media> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.media_view, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView fName, fSub, fDuration, fSize;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.media_view, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.fName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvfname);
            viewHolder.fSub = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvsub);
            viewHolder.fDuration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvduration);
            viewHolder.fSize = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvsize);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setId(position);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(View v) {  
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;  
                    int id = cb.getId();  
                    if (selection[id]) {  
                        cb.setChecked(false);  
                        selection[id] = false;  
                    } else {  
                        cb.setChecked(true);  
                        selection[id] = true;  
                    }  
                }  
            });  
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.fName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.fSub.setText(list.get(position).getPath());
        // Converting duration from String to Long
        long milli = Long.valueOf(list.get(position).getDuration());
        // Put it in % min, % sec format to display
        holder.fDuration.setText(String.format("%d:%d sec", 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milli),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milli) - 
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milli))
            ));

        // Convert data size from String to Long
        long datasize = Long.valueOf(list.get(position).getData());
        // Put in human readable format
        holder.fSize.setText(readableFileSize(datasize));
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    final ArrayList<Integer> posSel = new ArrayList<Integer>();  

    posSel.clear();  
    storeSelectedMedia.clear();

    /*
     * Construct the list of selected items
     */
    boolean noSelect = false;  
    Log.i("MediaSelection", "" + selection.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {  
        if (selection[i] == true) { 
            noSelect = true;  
            Log.e("Mediasel pos thu-->", "" + i);  
            posSel.add(i);  
            storeSelectedMedia.add(getMediaList.get(i).getPath());
        }  
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_refresh:
        try {
            rescanSdcard();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Action refresh selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
        break;

    case R.id.action_findfile:
        if (noSelect) {
        if (storeSelectedMedia.size() > 0) {

            for (String file : storeSelectedMedia) {
                try {
                    // Doing something
                    Log.i("Media", file.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,  
                            "Exception: '" + e.getMessage(),  
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

My log related to Log.i ("Media")
I selected 7 files. but it only show 6 in the log.

```
    04-11 00:31:26.879: I/MediaSelection(23155): 22
04-11 00:31:26.879: E/Mediasel pos thu-->(23155): 0
04-11 00:31:26.879: E/Mediasel pos thu-->(23155): 1
04-11 00:31:26.879: E/Mediasel pos thu-->(23155): 2
04-11 00:31:26.879: E/Mediasel pos thu-->(23155): 3
04-11 00:31:26.879: E/Mediasel pos thu-->(23155): 4
04-11 00:31:26.879: E/Mediasel pos thu-->(23155): 5
04-11 00:31:26.889: I/Media(23155): /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/VIDEO0001.3gp
04-11 00:31:26.889: I/Media(23155): /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/VIDEO0002.3gp
04-11 00:31:26.889: I/Media(23155): /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/VIDEO0004.mp4
04-11 00:31:26.889: I/Media(23155): /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/VIDEO0001.mp4
04-11 00:31:26.889: I/Media(23155): /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/VIDEO0002.mp4
04-11 00:31:26.889: I/Media(23155): /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/VIDEO0003.mp4
04-11 00:31:27.059: I/MediaSize(23155): 22
04-11 00:31:52.243: I/MediaSelection(23155): 22
04-11 00:31:52.243: E/Mediasel pos thu-->(23155): 0
04-11 00:31:52.243: I/Media(23155): /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/VIDEO0001.3gp
04-11 00:31:52.353: I/MediaSize(23155): 22
```

Not sure where gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `ViewHolder` pattern, then you need to understand that you don't have a `ViewHolder` for each item in your list. You only have a `ViewHolder` for each of the `View`s that Android is recycling for you. If you can fit 6 items on the display, then you will probably have something like 8 or 9 `ViewHolder`s. This means that when `getView()` is called, you need to update everything in the `ViewHolder` that is related to the item being displayed. In your case, that means you need to move this code:

```
    viewHolder.checkbox.setId(position);
    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
```

out of the `if` block and do it in **all cases** (whether you just created a `ViewHolder` or if you just recycled one). I would do it like this:

```
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    viewHolder.checkbox.setId(position);
```

Also, you should declare your `ViewHolder` class as `static`, as it doesn't need a reference to the surrounding class.

Comment: I have followed your method and it seem to be working. I will do some more test to ensure that it is working perfectly. I have moved viewHolder to before if (convertView == null) and I can't put static, as it will state as illegal. Right now, I have removed final. Is that alright?

Comment: No, I meant you should define the **class** as static: `private static class ViewHolder`, not the variable. Otherwise, yes, move the declaration of the variable `viewHolder` to before the `if` block and remove `final` because you will either create a new one (inside the `if`) or set the variable using `view.getTag()` in the `else` clause.